# change color for several characters in word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to change color for all vowel sounds, I found a piece of code for constant, could you please help to change this into set of letters, i.e., a, e, i, o, u?

```
Sub ChangeLetterColor()
    Const LETTER_TO_CHANGE = "a"
    Const COLOR_TO_CHANGE_TO = wdRed

    For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Range.Characters.Count
        If ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i) = LETTER_TO_CHANGE Then
            ThisDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = COLOR_TO_CHANGE_TO
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear where your specific problem lies. Could you please explain where the difficulty lies?

Comment: I don't know how to use array or variables properly.  I have text and I need all vowel sounds in red color, as vowel sounds are "a,e,i,o,u" it's not possible to use constant with just one letter, in this case "a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to put all characters that you want to change the color of into a string and then check for each character in your string whether it is contained in that string:

```
Sub ChangeLetterColor()
    Const LETTERS_TO_CHANGE = "aeiou"
    Const COLOR_TO_CHANGE_TO = wdRed

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentLetter As String

    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Range.Characters.Count
        currentLetter = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(i)
        If InStr(1, LETTERS_TO_CHANGE, currentLetter, vbTextCompare) Then
            ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = COLOR_TO_CHANGE_TO
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```